# enable CORS for local http server

Tags: macos, cors, httpserver

I hosted my local files with http server. Just install on my Mac HTTP server with command:

```
npm install --global http-server
```

Then I start this server in needed directory with the command:

```
http-server
```

I had the CORS policy problem when trying to fetch my local HTML file from HTTP server response. It was blocked.
[image: Blocked by CORS policy]

Comment: you can also use npx http-server ... params

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All I need to do for resolving this issue just to start HTTP server with cors option:

```
http-server --cors
```

Comment: Is there a particular order the arguments have to be in? I have `--cors` and it is not working for me.

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to pass that argument to your task (e.g. in your Terminal). In my case I added it to my package.json "start-server" script ( "start-server": "http-server --cors -c-1 -p 8081") @Cody

Comment: it didn't work for me, the problem was that the CORS headers (probably the options request call) is cached. When I disabled cache, it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Was unable to get `http-server` running with CORS support (different browsers, disabling cache... nothing helped).

As the [related bug ticket](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/394) is still an ongoing discussion, here is an alternative that worked for me out of the box using [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server):

1. `npm i local-web-server --global`
2. `ws --cors.origin http://<your domain> --cors.credentials`

You might add `--https -p 443` if you need to simulate local SSL support.

Comment: http-server worked for me with --cors flag. Make sure you use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is simply [serve package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) via `npx`

eg. `npx serve ./folder -l 3003 --cors`

The port can be dropped or specified